# Typing a variable in cypress and then pressing enter

Tags: cypress

I am trying to pass a variable to a cypress function to type and then press enter.

I have found that this doesn't work.

```
const valToType = "ABCD"
cy.get('#MyID').type(valToType).type('{enter}');
```

I have seen elsewhere the workaround is to do

```
cy.get('#MyID').type('ABCD{enter}');
```

However I'd really like to keep this a variable. Anyone know how this is possible with cypress?

Comment: What error are you getting for the first attempt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use string interpolation to pass your variable and press the enter key in a single `type()` command, like this:

```
cy.get('#MyID').type(`${valToType}{enter}`);
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to wrap your variable like this:

```
const valToType = "ABCD"
cy.wrap(valToType).then((val) => {
    cy.get('#MyID').type(val).type('{enter}');
})
```

Comment: It is not necessary to wrap the variable in this instance. You would want to wrap the variable and add an alias for it if you wish to context share across test steps, but for this scenario it would work without doing so.

Comment: it could be necessary since cypress is asynchronous and could be the reason why the user code doesn't work
anyway my above code works nice